# Same applications share the static variables when accessed through browser

Tags: wpf, browser, activex, static-members

I have two different WPF apps...both are accessed through Internet Explorer as Active Ex.

app1 - is using the DLLs in C:\ProgFiles(86)\app1

and

app2 - is using the DLLs in C:\ProgFiles(86)\app2

And both have some common DLLs...and these DLLs have some static variables.

when I access thse static variabled from one application (ex:app1)..and after that if I try to access it from the other app (ex: app2)...the first value is getting used.

Can anyone tell me what should I do in this case?

Comment: activeX? WPF? Huh? You do realize you created a horrible monster, right?

Comment: I know :(..it is a requirement ...